# LinqToSQL: Using custom methods to calculate expressions

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, date-conversion

I'm running a Linq To SQL query and would like to retrieve a calculated column based on some settings in my table,  I want to add a time unit to a date field.

I'm running the following:

```
var q = from p in db.PublicHolidays
select new {
     Holiday = s.Holiday,
     ReminderDay = Convert.ToDateTime(p.Holiday).AddByUnit(p.ReminderUnits, -p.ReminderQuantity)
};
```

On my date calculation I get an error that `'System.DateTime' does not contain a definition for 'AddByUnit'` .

Intellisense does bring up AddByUnit so I'm not sure what is wrong.  Removing the explicit date conversion gives the same error

Comment: That definitely does not exist. Maybe your own extension method? Even Google only find 2 results...

Comment: What is the type of `Holiday`? What is the `AddByUnit`?

Comment: Yes, that is actually a custom method.  It came from so long ago that I forgot it was an extension and not a system method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message says, the method `AddByUnit` (probably an `extension method`) was not found to run at runtime. Make sure your code can see this method.

### Important tip for you Linq to Sql

You cannot use an custom method into a `linq-to-sql`. Depending of the provider you are using, it will not support because `linq-to-sql` will try to transform your `linq query` into `sql query`. Try to bring it the property you need to a `anonymous object` into a concrete result and lead with this in memory. For sample.

```
// call ToList() to execute it on database and bring to memory.    
var list = (from p in db.PublicHolidays
            select new {
                Holiday = s.Holiday,
                ReminderUnits = p.ReminderUnits
                ReminderQuantity = p.ReminderQuantity
            }).ToList();

// use it in memory
var result = list.Select(x => new {
                  Holiday = x.Holiday,
                  ReminderDay = Convert.ToDateTime(x.Holiday).AddByUnit(x.ReminderUnits, -p.ReminderQuantity))
              }).ToList();
```

Comment: The OP has a compiler error. Your answer is something different that will only err at runtime.

Comment: Makes sense.  Thanks.  I'll change to title of the question to be more applicable.